# Compile an html template with data from my controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In Angular,I am building a web app for an hotel that has different rooms. I want to be able to click on a tab in the navbar (or anywhere on the page.) and populate the html view with public data about the room that I have stored in the controller. 
what is the best way to go about this? I am using ui-routing. I have yet to find an exhaustive answer on stack overflow.

Below is an example of what my app looks like.

This is my app.js

```js
var appBB = angular
.module('appBB', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', MainRouter]);

function MainRouter(states, router) {
    states
    .state( 'home', {
      url:'/',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
  }).state( 'show',{
      url:'/show',
      templateUrl:'show.html'
  });
    router.otherwise('/');
}
```

This is my controller

```js
appBB.controller("BBController", BBController());

function BBController() {
    var self = this;

    self.apartments = [
        {
        name: "apt1",
        image: "imag1.jpg"
        amenities: ["blablabal", "bhuhuih", "hvjf"]
        },

        {
        name: "apt2",
        image: "img2.jpg",
        amenities: ["blablabla", "bkjhkg", "lkhug"]
        },

        {
        name: "apt3",
        image: "img3.jpg",
        amenities: ["blablabla", "jgfkhgc","jgvkhg"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is an example of the view template that I want to fill:

```html
<div ng-controller="BBController as bbs">

    <div>
         <h4>{{this should show the apt name}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-8">
               <img ng-src="{{this should show the image of the apt that i  clicked on}}" />                     
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="looping over the apt amenities">{{amenity}}</li>              </ul>
         </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify the controller in your router states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing looks good but you need some improvement in it.I would suggest you to use `$routeParams` on Nav-bar clicks. something like:

```
<div ng-controller="BBController as bbs">

<div>
     <h4>{{this should show the apt name}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8">
           <img ng-src="{{this should show the image of the apt that i  clicked on}}" />                     
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
         <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="amemity in amenities">
            <a ng-href="#amemityList/{{ amemity.id }}"> {{amemity.name}} </a>
           </li> 
         </ul>
     </div>          
</div>
```

Now, you can use this `amenity.id` to pass to `YourController` and accordingly fetch respective view with all the info of that "clicked" `amenity.id`

```
.when('/amemityList/:navBar', {
            templateUrl: "AmenityView.html",
            controller: "YourController"
        })
```

In this way, you will be able to use single view `AmenityView.html` and its info can be as per your `amenity.id` which has been passed to the controller like

```
var navBarSelection_id = $routeParams.navBar;
```

Comment: Thank you, I had this in my controller after the show: 


.state('/showSingle/:num', {
      url:'/showSingle/:num',
      templateUrl:'show_single.html',
      controller: 'BBController'

});


it does not seem to help because I am getting this error: Error: Could not resolve 'showSingle/1' from state 'show' ---

Comment: Yep, you can associate it with each element on nav-bar :) . Its cool and simple

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could add the info at the url like /show/apt1 and use apt1 to find the information on the controller.

Edit:

A little explanation: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07